# Passing an integer from a customcursoradapter to an activity 

Tags: android, android-intent, bind, custom-cursor

Can I use the same process that you use to pass data between different activities will this work for the passing of data between an activity and an cursoradapter.
The error generated is not run time is compilation

```
The constructor Intent(MyAdapterQuestion, Class<Basic_database_questionsActivity>) is undefined

Intent i = new Intent(MyAdapterQuestion.this, Basic_database_questionsActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            // get the current value of timerStart variable and store it in timerlogic
            //Log.e(LOGS, "Whatis the value of timerstart inside the intentcalls method" + aInt);

            b.putInt("timerlogic", aInt);
```

I have an adapter named MyAdapterQuestion and an activity called Basic_database_questionsActivity.

I have a counter which is inside the method bindView method

```
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

     if(radiopos1.isChecked())
        {

          // i want to update my main activity 
    // this method increment the correct answer by one I want to get that value and //pass it back to the activity      
    correctAnswer();

        }

    }
```

Comment: for the love of god, learn to format your code! this is so bad it's almost offensive!

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot send an Intent to an adapter. The Activity created the adapter so it should be able to communicate with it. Either by calling a method, passing a parameter in a constructor, etc.

**EDIT: Add code example**

If the adapter needs to call a method in the Activity, you could do something like this:

In MyAdapterQuestion:

```
// Stores a reference to the owning activity
private Basic_database_questionsActivity activity;

// Sets the owning activity (caller should call this immediately after constructing
//  the adapter)
public void setActivity(Basic_database_questionsActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

// When you want to call a method in your activity (to get or set data), you do
//   something like this:
activity.setCorrectAnswer(answer);
```

In Basic_database_questionsActivity:

```
// In the place where you create the adapter, do this:
MyAdapterQuestion adapter = new MyAdapterQuestion(parameters...);
adapter.setActivity(this); // Passes a reference of the Activity to the Adapter

public void setCorrectAnswer(int answer) {
    // Here is where the adapter calls the activity back
    ...
}
```

I hope you get the idea. You just need a way for the Adapter to get a reference to the Activity so that it can call methods on it if necessary.

**Note:** Better programming style would be to include the Activity as a parameter in your Adapter constructor, but since you didn't post the code for your Adapter constructor I didn't want to confuse you too much.

Comment: could you give an example please David to see if I understand the answer clearly.

Comment: I added a code example. Have you resolved your issue? Do you need more help?